# how to add style to label for show a string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, label, nsattributedstring

I want to use style Number in the label.like to below photo.
but I haven't the idea for it.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTzmA.jpg)

Comment: You won't be able to that with basic `NSAttributedString`. You might need to play with CoreText, and do plenty of effects that are "quickly" done on Photoshop (or any other advanced image app), but not programmitaclly.

Comment: also its spelled 'Congratulations'

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

  let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"0123456789").invertedSet
  let compSepByCharInSet = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(aSet)
  let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joinWithSeparator("")
  return string == numberFiltered

}
```

Comment: ı don't understand fully but maybe you can use this